# What part of speech is "semblant" in?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

**"Elle fait semblant de boire."**

Is *semblant* a noun or an adjective here?

Answer (score 9):

There is no adjective *semblant* although it existed as such in old French.

Here, ***semblant*** is part of the idiom ***faire semblant*** which means "to simulate", "pretend", "feign".

*Semblant* alone is the *participe présent* (present participle) of the verb *sembler* or the noun derived from it.

Answer (score 2):

*Semblant* is the present continuous form of the verb *sembler*. The usual adjective would be *semblable*. The present continuous form can be substantivised, as in *le prétendant* (and indeed, *le semblant*) and it can be adjectival, *café chantant*, *place payante*...

Idiomatic constructions with *faire* can take either a noun or an adjective, as in *faire le con* (noun, as evident from *le*), *faire partie* (noun, even though there is no article present) *cela fait drôle* (adjective, but idioms in the class are viewed as low-brow); *cela fait chic*

*On fait semblant de chanter*, for instance. This *de* might make one lean toward *semblant* being adjectival in this context, as we also say things like *cela fait chic d'arriver légèrement en retard*.

Comment: Not to be confused with the noun "prétendant(e)" which is mostly used to qualify a lover.